# Building framework.jar in AOSP

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to build a framework.jar from android-x86 aosp but 'mm' in /frameworks/base return "No such file or directory". And also I tried "make framework" but after that framework.jar size in out 300 bytes. I tried "make modules" to get framework module name but list so long. May be somebody know what module name for build complete framework.jar ?

Update: I don't know why mm and mmm don't work for me, but I understand thats "make framework" work correctly, after android 5.0 java classes compiling in ART .oat and .odex files. But I try to reverse emulator framework.jar that have framework.jar fro dalvik with .dex files inside. And it confused me when I compared the builded and emulator file.

Comment: Have you setup the build environment first ? Also you should run mm -B to build the dependencies  as well.

Comment: @khetanrajesh I have installed jdk7, jde7, sync repo and 'make' command work for full build, but have some errors when it building chromium. After some research I found that in some builds framework.jar does not contain .dex files and it size about 300 bytes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you should have these in your `~/.bashrc` when, and do a full build/flash. Otherwise making and building just parts of framework will cause the device to not boot. These will cause the first boot to be a tad slower since the pre-optimizations are not done at build time.

```
export WITH_DEXPREOPT=false 
export DISABLE_DEXPREOPT=true
export DEX_PREOPT_DEFAULT=nostripping
```

Next build, you can run just

```
source build/setupenv.sh 
lunch XXXXX-userdebug 
make framework
```

And to update on device

```
adb root
adb remount
adb sync
adb reboot
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, and answer. I am sure it will work.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking at this in 2023 for Android 13 (API 33), to build `framework.jar`, follow this instead:

`make framework-minus-apex`

Ref: [frameworks/base/Android.bp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-13.0.0_r37/Android.bp#373)

Secondly, IMHO, to access any custom APIs in application side, the best way is to create a JAR from the required Manager classes and import in Android Studio as a dependency instead of adding a bulky `framework.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Try running below command from AOSP main directory:

```
mmm frameworks/base/
```

Comment: Have you run command "$. build/envsetup.sh" from AOSP main directory? If not then please run this command followed by lunch command according to your device name e.g. "lunch aosp_hammerhead-userdebug". Moreover you can check whether this command is present in AOSP/build/envsetup.sh file. All supported build commands should be present there.

Comment: "lunch" working and "mm" in envsetup.sh but "mm" and "mmm" don't work anyway :(

Comment: @S__ Your envsetup.sh should've had the mmm command, since it's a standard one. Anyways "mmm frameworks/base/" is equivalent of " cd frameworks/base/  ; and then mm"  so you can use that.

Note that if you'll have to build first frameworks/base/core/res/ to build the frameworks-res.apk ( otherwise framework/base compilation will throw an error" )

Comment: @RickSanchez, That makes sense. So, do you know the solution to build framework?

Comment: @XueQing What I needed to say was too big for a comment, so i posted an answer. See that.

Answer (score 0):

First setup environment by this command :

```
source build/setupenv.sh
```

Second lunch your target

```
lunch your-target
```

Third use this command to build framework.jar

```
mmm framework/base
```

> if you have any problem or error , clean the  source directory first and then run the third command

```
make clean
```

Comment: In the third command, the correct path is frameworks/base. It's missing a "s".